# why do I get a smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: Error?

Tags: python, windows, gmail, smtplib

So basically I am trying to develop  a python program that lets me send emails to my friend's email without signing in. However I get a Error that says `smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused`:

Here is my code..

```
    import smtplib

    myemail = 'myemail@gmail.com'
    mypassword = 'password'
    friendemail = input('Please enter the email of the person:')
    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587) as smtp:
         subject = input("Subject: ")
         body = input('Message:')
         msg = f"subject:{subject}\n\n{body}"

         smtp.starttls()
         smtp.login(myemail,mypassword)
         smtp.sendmail(myemail, mypassword, msg)
```

It would be great if anyone could help! Thank YOU!

Comment: currently GMail may need to generate special password for your program or you may need in GMail's setttings set "accept untrusted connections/programs"

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: [Sign in with App Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) and [Less secure apps & your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)

Comment: @Savo Rodrigues Has the issue you mentioned been solved effectively?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run the code you provided, and there was a problem with the image below, right?

[image]

According to the prompt, I changed the parameters of sendmail.

> `smtp.sendmail(myemail, friendemail, msg)`

The parameters here represent: sender's mailbox, recipient's mailbox, and email content.

After the change, I successfully ran it in vscode and sent an email to my friend's Gmail email.

Note: the email name and password should be filled in correctly and can not be omitted.